# solr replication Solr index compatible

Tags: indexing, solr

In the Solr master slave replication, the high version Solr (4.+) synchronization low version Solr index appears the following problem:
ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller  – Master at: http://xxx:3739/core is not avaiable. Index fetch failed. Exception: Invalid version (expected 2, but 1) or the data in not in 'javabin' format

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please improve formatting of your question. It is not readable, nor clear what/where is the problem.

Comment: Dear Hamid Rohani thanks for your answer;My problem is the high version of the Solr synchronization low version Solr the index failed.

Comment: and the logger is 
ERROR org.apache.solr.handler.SnapPuller – Master at: http://xxx:3739/core is not avaiable. Index fetch failed. Exception: Invalid version (expected 2, but 1) or the data in not in 'javabin' format

Comment: Dear @lylrian, I tried to edit and improve readability of your question, but I can't understand the structure of your question sentence. Please read [Markdown Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages to learn how to format your question. Unformatted questions aren't interesting for other users to answer. Below of your question there is an `edit` link. Click on it and improve the formatting (separate error section, describe what you have done, what happened, configuration, ...).

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issues, which the Solr version was migrated to 5.5.0 from 4.6.1. I have tried multiple options, one thing that worked for me was to re-index the data again.

Point to note: Fetchindex from old Solr collection to new Solr collection didn't worked for me.

My main need was to use Block Join (the parent and child document relation) feature of Solr.